# Geometric van der waerden theorem

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Van der Waerden theorem states that sufficiently long initial segment of the natural numbers when divided into $r$ parts contains an arithmetic progression of length $k$. The length of the initial segment is denoted as $W(k,r)$ which is called as the van der Waerden number.

I am looking for papers and research articles on a version of the same theorem where instead of arithmetic progressions we are guaranteed geometric progressions. The geometric van der Waerden theorem is a corollary to van der Waerden's theorem. In particular has any work been done on geometric van der Waerden numbers?

Comment: I have seen it as an exercise at several places but what is your question?

Comment: They are just equal to $G(k,r)=2^{W(k,r)-1}$. One inequality is obvious. For the other one, color $\prod_p p^{m_p}< G(k,r)$ by the color $c(1+\sum_p m_p)$. The general moral is that no literature search beats good old thinking process.

Comment: @fedja: Is it possible to just use logarithms and reduce the multiplicative version to the additive version?

Comment: @fedja: In your lower bound what is the coloring? What is $c$?

Comment: @fedja: In your colouring, geometric progressions such as $\{ 3^n, 2 \times 3^{n-1}, 2^2 \times 3^{n-2}, \dots, 2^{n-1} \times 3, 2^n \}$ are monochromatic. Your answer works if we insist that the common ratio is an integer, though.

Comment: I think that the sum of squares $c(1 + \sum_p m_p^2)$ should work by Bezout's theorem in algebraic geometry (specifically, a line can intersect a sphere in at most two points). That's not quite as tight as fedja's bound.

Comment: Oops, this doesn't work as stated, since $c(1 + \sum_p m_p^2)$ is non-linear and therefore does not yield an arithmetic progression. And any linear function would fail by the same argument as my previous comment.

Comment: @Adam P. Goucher Ah, I see now. My understanding of the question was exactly as you said (integer denominator) but, indeed, there is absolutely no reason why rational denominators should be excluded from the game. OK, I'll think more of it :). The moral stays, however.

Answer (score 2):

Fedja has already answered one possible interpretation of your question in a comment, where the common ratio is required to be an integer. Here's further explanation, together with a multiplicative analogue of van der Waerden's theorem which is equivalent to Gallai-Witt. In what follows, I'm taking $\mathbb{N} = \{ 1, 2, 3, \dots \}$.

There's a straightforward isomorphism between the monoid $\mathbb{N}$ under multiplication and the direct sum $\mathbb{N} \oplus \mathbb{N} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{N}$ (with countably many copies of $\mathbb{N}$) under addition; the explicit bijection is $2^{a_1} 3^{a_2} 5^{a_3} \dots \rightarrow (a_1 + 1, a_2 + 1, a_3 + 1, \dots)$. Geometric progressions in $\mathbb{N}$ correspond to arithmetic progressions in the direct sum (henceforth abbreviated to $\mathbb{N}^{\omega}$, in a slight abuse of notation).

Fedja's answer involves colouring the points of $\mathbb{N}^{\omega}$ according to their sum (so hyperplanes perpendicular to $(1, 1, 1, \dots)$ have constant colour). Any geometric progression in $\mathbb{N}$ would correspond to an arithmetic progression in $\mathbb{N}^{\omega}$, which is then mapped to an arithmetic progression in $\mathbb{N}$. If the common ratio of the geometric progression is required to be an integer greater than $1$, then all the terms of the resulting arithmetic progression are distinct (otherwise, rational ratios such as $r = \frac{3}{2}$ give a non-injective map).

Anyway, even allowing rational ratios, I can still establish a weak bound in the opposite direction to the trivial bound. Given $G = G(k,r)$, the isomorphism gives a subset of $[\lceil \log_2{G} \rceil]^{\pi(G)}$, where $\pi$ is the prime-counting function. Now, we colour a point $(a_1 + 1, a_2 + 1, a_3 + 1, \dots)$ by $c(1 + a_1 \lceil \log_2{G} \rceil + a_2 (\lceil \log_2{G} \rceil)^2 + \dots)$, where (as in Fedja's answer) $c(n)$ is the colour of $n$ in the worst-case colouring for van der Waerden's theorem, establishing the following *very weak* bounds:

$$\lceil \log_2{G(k,r)} \rceil \leq W(k,r) \leq (\lceil \log_2{G(k,r)} \rceil)^{\pi(G(k,r))}$$

A refinement of this argument gives $W(k,r) \leq \prod_{p < \pi(G)} (\lceil \log_p{G(k,r)} \rceil)$.

---

On a related topic, the *Gallai-Witt theorem* states that, given a finite set $S \subset \mathbb{N}^n$ and a $k$-colouring of $\mathbb{N}^n$, we can find some scaled and translated copy of $S$ that is monochromatic. Using our isomorphism, this can be pulled back to a multiplicative statement in $\mathbb{N}$. Indeed, this multiplicative theorem seems to be shorter than the original Gallai-Witt theorem:

Given a finite set of naturals $\{ b_1, b_2, b_3, \dots, b_n \} \subset \mathbb{N}$ and a $k$-colouring of $\mathbb{N}$, we can find constants $A, B$ such that $\{ A b_1^B, A b_2^B, \dots, Ab_n^B \}$ is a monochromatic set.

The additive version of this statement is trivially equivalent to van der Waerden's theorem.

Comment: Could you explain the definition of $c(n)$?

Comment: "where (as in Fedja's answer) c(n)  is the colour of n  in the worst-case colouring for van der Waerden's theorem"